# What gets displayed on a map

Tags: wordpress, map

When enabling mapping for a profile that e.g. includes the field ZIPCODE only - and then allowing mapping for all contacts (i.e. `?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/profile/map&reset=1&gid=xyz`), contacts pop up on the map as intended. 
If I click on the individual icon, it then, however, gives me full details including NAME and exact ADDRESS; that's not what I want to share...

Is there a way of controlling which fields get shown on the map - not including them in the profile somehow does not do the job.

This is all in WP.

Cheers